# What should I do if, when uploading changes to GitHub, the indentation at the beginning of the line increases?

Tags: reactjs, git, visual-studio-code, github

I have a problem that when uploading changes to GitHub, the indentation at the beginning of the line increases, to explain myself I will attach screenshots [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sglKD.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4rVX.png)

At the same time, when I write `git add .` in the terminal, a warning appears `warning: in the working copy of 'App.jsx', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it` and so on for all changed files, but for me is in the settings CRLF and not LF [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o28T.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvjPO.png)

Also in the JSON user settings there is this line `"files.eol": "\r\n",`

I'm just learning, please don't judge strictly. :) I tried to describe the problem as best as possible

I want help to make sure that the indentation at the beginning of the line does not increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a mater of eol.

I think you are using tabs to indent your code and the default size in GitHub is big (equivalent of 8 spaces). That's why you see a big difference...

You just have to change it in your settings: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-user-account-settings/managing-your-tab-size-rendering-preference

Tabs vs space is a long debate:

- tabs are best because everyone could choose the indent size (especially useful for those having a visual handicap)
- spaces are better at rendering *always* the same way (like the problem you have here)
- if you use tabs instead of spaces, you will be more payed  https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot. It's good that there are people like you :)